# Copy records into a table and update parent record id relationship

Tags: postgresql

I need to duplicate records in a table that have a parent child relationship. Since the new records will have a new record id, the parent/child relationship needs to be preserved and updated to reflect the new record IDs (primary keys).

Lets say I have the following table:

```
asset_id   parent_asset_id
    1        NULL
    5         1
    23        1
    25        23
```

When I copy the records into the table, they look like this:

```
asset_id   parent_asset_id
    42        NULL
    43        1
    44        1
    45        23
```

I need the new asset-to-parent relationship to be as follows:

```
asset_id   parent_asset_id
    42        NULL
    43        42
    44        42
    45        44
```

I am trying to use CTE (but maybe this is not the best approach). I update the current `asset.asset` table with the new records and then want to update the parent child relationship, but can't figure out how to join tables to get the relationship correct.

`parent_asset_id` is the column that needs to be have the correct relationship, all other fields stay the same.

```
CREATE FUNCTION asset.copy_asset_store(
    IN _username VARCHAR(100),
    IN _src_asset_store_id VARCHAR,
    IN _dest_asset_store_id VARCHAR
)

DECLARE
    v_user_id INT;

 BEGIN

    WITH copy_into_study AS(
    UPDATE
        asset.asset
    SET
        origin_asset_id = original.origin_asset_id,
        asset_type_id = original.asset_type_id,
        asset_store_id = _dest_asset_store_id,
        parent_asset_id = original.parent_asset_id
        asset_name = original.asset_name,
        asset_desc = original.asset_desc,
        is_signature_required = original.is_signature_required,
        s3_bucket_id = original.s3_bucket_id,
        color_id = original.color_id,
        asset_expiration = original.asset_expiration,
        is_deleted = original.is_deleted,
        rec_created_by_user_id = v_user_id,
        rec_updated_by_user_id = v_user_id
    FROM
        asset.asset AS original
    WHERE
        original.asset_store_id = _src_asset_store_id::INT
    RETURNING *
    ),update_parent AS (
        UPDATE
            asset.asset
        SET
            parent_asset_id = copy_into_study.parent_asset_id
        FROM 
            copy_into_study
        WHERE 

    )
```

Comment: Where does the asset_id comes from? How do you know about the child/parent relationship? Where is the connection to the old table... Please explain a litte bit more detailed about what you are trying to do. Maybe add a fiddle with some data

Comment: `asset_id` is a primary key. Parent asset id will be given to me by the front-end when someone updates or creates a new record. It is based on where they store the asset(file). Root directory or a subfolder of the root directory.

Comment: You mean its an autoincremental value which is given to you after the INSERT? That sounds like a really bad idea: You want to copy records but don't know which value they get without any connection to the old values and try to reconstruct the parent relationship afterwards on these values?

Comment: The most simple way is: Copying the original values, add + 1000 or something and reset the autoincrementation counter to the next highest value manually afterwards.

Comment: @S-Man  you are correct that it is an auto-increment value that I don't know what it will be until after the insert. Databases are all very new to me and trying to figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: @S-Man. Also, not sure if this helps, but there is a connection. When I copy the records, I also copy the parent asset id. So there is some connection, and I have been trying to work with the fact the the old and new records have the same `parent_asset_id` and then try to figure out how to manipulate the data and update it.

Comment: Please add this to your sample data

Comment: @S-Man I updated the example to show what the copy will look like and then what it should look like.

Comment: This is really a hard, highly potential errorneous case. My advice stays: Copy the data with a fixed offset that ensures every id is higher than every id the new_table already contains. And then increase the serial counter manually. That's the most safe way I currently see in this setup. Every other case is complecated or hacky or both. And this has high risk of errors.

Comment: Maybe there is something I don't understand..but don't you know the new asset_id especially when using CTE or just in general... postgres has this information. I know the asset name, i know the original parent asset id and I should know the new `asset_id`